# How to make QT layout automatically scale to fill the window when it's resized?

Tags: python, qt, qt-creator

I'm writing a program with QT creator and Python and i have a basic vertical layout with a tabwidget and some other stuff in the tab widget. What i want to do is make it so the tab widget automatically scales to fit the window when its resized. I tried right clicking on the top level Qwidget and laying everything out in a grid, and that did fix the gaps on the sides but the widget doesn't scale when the window is resized.

[image]

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>Widget</class>
<widget class="QWidget" name="Widget">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<width>800</width>
<height>575</height>
</rect>
</property>
<property name="windowTitle">
<string>Widget</string>
</property>
<layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
<item row="0" column="0">
<layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
<property name="sizeConstraint">
<enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
</property>
<item>
<widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
<property name="sizePolicy">
<sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
<horstretch>0</horstretch>
<verstretch>0</verstretch>
</sizepolicy>
</property>
<property name="maximumSize">
<size>
<width>16777214</width>
<height>16777215</height>
</size>
</property>
<widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
<attribute name="title">
<string>Tab 1</string>
</attribute>
<widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
<x>3</x>
<y>9</y>
<width>771</width>
<height>441</height>
</rect>
</property>
</widget>
<widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit_2">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
<x>3</x>
<y>459</y>
<width>771</width>
<height>61</height>
</rect>
</property>
</widget>
</widget>
<widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
<attribute name="title">
<string>Tab 2</string>
</attribute>
</widget>
</widget>
</item>
</layout>
</item>
</layout>
</widget>
<resources/>
<connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show your code -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

This works:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Widget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Widget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>947</width>
    <height>723</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Widget</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <property name="maximumSize">
      <size>
       <width>16777214</width>
       <height>16777215</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
      <attribute name="title">
       <string>Tab 1</string>
      </attribute>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
       <item>
        <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit"/>
         <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit_2"/>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
      <attribute name="title">
       <string>Tab 2</string>
      </attribute>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

### What was wrong

You have added a layout to the widget instead of setting it as the Widget's layout. In the right click menu you will find the option to assign a layout to the widget(Which you did not do).

Comment: I copy pasta'd the your ui file into my project but its still doing the same thing.